# Spring Roo JSPX and form tag

Tags: forms, tags, spring-roo, jspx

I am trying to use the form tag within a Spring Roo JSPX file:   But everytime I run the application, I keep getting the following exception:

The prefix "form" for element "form:form" is not bound.

I have the form tag library included (xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"). Can anyone help me get started on troubleshoot this error message?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to check maven repositories, dependencies and its versions in **pom.xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

In XML files every tag has to be bounded with a closing tag. For Example  has to be closed with  tag. Usually in html files you don't need to close link tags, but in Spring and other xml formats like jspx, you have to close these tags.